# Does encodeURICOmponent work in js?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have files by name booksearch.js and admin.java. I need to pass a value of uri from booksearch.js to admin.java. The value of uri has the special character '+' so I did use encodeURIComponent in booksearch.js. I alerted the uri in an alert box and after encodeURIComponent the value of uri was encoded properly. But when I pass this encoded value to admin.java by using getParameter() function. The value of uri does not have the '+' sign.

What have I done wrong here?

The code of booksearch.js is

```
    function editBook(uri, properties){
    var params = ""; 
    for (var property in properties[0])

        params += "&" + property + "=" + properties[0][property];

        alert("This is the uri "+uri);
     uri=encodeURIComponent(uri);

        alert("The new uri is "+uri);
$.ajax({
    url: "Admin?action=edit&uri=" + uri + params,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response){
        $("#output").append(response);
    }
});

  }
```

The code in admin.java is

```
          if (action.equals("edit")) {
        String uri = request.getParameter("uri");

        System.out.println("this is the uri of the new book added "+uri);
```

The output is

In the first alert box of uri I get

This is the uri http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#BestSeller in C++

The new uri is http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#BestSeller in C++

after getparameter I get the output as

this is the uri of the new book added http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#BestSeller in C

What is happening?

Regards,

Archana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong here. The `getParameter()` just URL-decodes the values back to their normal forms.

If you rather want the raw (URL-encoded) query string, use [`request.getQueryString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29). You only need to parse it in further parameters yourself.

Comment: Then why even if getParameter() decodes the uri then how come I am not getting ++ in the uri after using getParameter()?

Comment: If everything is correct then can someone tell me why I am not retrieving ++ sign after passing the uri?